# Calling setMode without clearing audiosession category options

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

It seems that if I have a set category

```
// example
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .voiceChat, options: [.allowBluetooth, .defaultToSpeaker])
```

then, some period later, I call

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
```

My audio sessions category parameters (i.e. [.allowBluetooth, .defaultToSpeaker]) are completely wiped by the `setMode` invocation.

**Is there a way I can call setMode() without clearing the category options?**
It is useful to know, as it does appear that `setCategory()` takes a lot of time (blocking my main thread), while `setMode` is a much faster call.